# Convergence or divergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does this series 
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{\zeta{(k+1)}}{\zeta{(k)}}$$ converge  or diverge?

Here $$\zeta{(k)}=\dfrac{1}{1^k}+\dfrac{1}{2^k}+\dfrac{1}{3^k}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n^k}+\cdots $$
If it converges, how to find the value?

If it diverges, how to prove it?

Thank you

Discussion for a while, and I have edited to a new problem.

How to find the result of this sum
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{\zeta{(k+1)}}{\zeta{(k)}}-1\right)$$

Comment: Did you think about it one minute? Hint: when $k\to\infty$, $\zeta(k)\to$ $____$, hence...

Comment: but This problem is $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}$$

Comment: Already with $\,k=1\,$ you have big problems since $\,\zeta(1)\;$ diverges...so what is the first summand in your series?!

Comment: e, Thank you, I'm sorry,

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ convergence, what can we say about $\lim a_n$? then go back to your problem.

Comment: The $k=1$ summand can be saved by setting $\zeta(2)/\zeta(1)=0$ since $\zeta(2)$ is finite and $\zeta(1)$ diverges.

Comment: @math110 Each of your two comments so far is mystery to me.

Comment: Or instead of putting $\,\zeta(2)/\zeta(1)=0\;$ we could simply begin the series from $\,k=2\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio,, Thank you

Comment: and @Did,Thank you  I have edit

Comment: And what about the hint in my first comment?

Comment: Perhaps a more interesting question would be $$\sum\left({\zeta(k+1)\over\zeta(k)}-1\right)$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson,How prove that ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson,are you  mean  that.$k\longrightarrow \infty,\zeta{(k)}\longrightarrow \zeta{(k+1)}$?

Comment: You're asking me, how do I prove that my question is more interesting than yours? Well, it can hardly be any *less* interesting.

Comment: What people have been trying to tell you is that $\zeta(n)\to1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @math110, I think that what Gerry meant is that the general term of *your* series doesn't converge to zero (and thus your series already diverges) but in fact to one, and thus the series he proposes has a generat term sequence that converges to zero...

Comment: sorry,my english is very poor, I don't know you mean @Gerry,Myerson

Comment: @GerryMyerson, in your last comment I think you forgot to write the whole quotient of zetas...

Comment: @Don, no, I wrote what I meant. What I wrote of course implies that the quotient goes to 1; what I wrote is how I know the quotient goes to 1.

Comment: Ok @Gerry, I just thought to point to the OP that its series cannot converge for the simplest of all the reasons.

Comment: Now ,I Confuse away..

Comment: @GerryMyerson,your mean this following series can find ?$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{\zeta{(k+1)}}{\zeta{(k)}}-1\right)$$

Comment: @math110, it perhaps would be a good idea that you try to improve your english a little: this is not the first time you say your english is poor and you confuse/don't understand stuff. As english is the most widely used language in mathematics (and many other things), you'll profit from improving it...and also you'll understand better what's going on here.

Comment: I would try to compare the zeta quotient with $1-2^{-k}$.

Comment: oh,@ Thank you,@DonAntonio, I study English everyday to until .

Comment: @Gerry Or, for every $a\geqslant0$, $$\sum\frac{\zeta(k+a)-1}{\zeta(k)}$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson Your question is quite a good question and the answer is almost $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}+0.0003961111\dots$

Answer (score 4):

Consider the sum $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{n^k}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n^{-2}}{1-n^{-1}}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=1.$$
As the above sum is absolutely convergent,$$1=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{n^k}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^k}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty(\zeta(k)-1).$$
Hence,$$0<\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{\zeta{(k)}}{\zeta{(k+1)}}-1\right)<\sum_{k=2}^\infty(\zeta(k)-1)=1.$$